# HTTPS using HTTP POST

Tags: java, android, post, https, passwords

I'm currently programming for Android 4.4 and I'm wanting to fill a web form with a username and password combination. This is obviously sensitive data, and I'm connecting to a HTTPS web page.

Is using the HTTP `POST` method sensible and encouraged for this or is there an alternate method I can use to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`HTTP Post` vs `HTTP GET`

in `GET` method you send the parameters part of the url string

in `POST` method you send the parameters part of the post body

`HTTP` vs `HTTPS`

in `HTTP` you send the request as plain text, very readable by 3rd party applications
in `HTTPS` you encrypt the contents of the request, and thus the 3rd party applications would need some additional keys to decrypt it.

the question of sensitivity depends on who do you want to hide the information from?

if from the user, HTTP POST is enough, the average user does not try to read the contents of http requests.

if from hackers, then you'd need HTTPS